# :active transition ended by :hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have these 3 rules:

```
.thingy{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width: 5em;
height: 5em;
background-color:#FF0000;
left:0em;
transition: left 4s linear, background-color 4s;
}

.thingy:active{
left:10em;
transition: left 0s linear;
}

.thingy:hover{
background-color:#00FF00;
transition: background-color 0s linear;
}
```

and this bit of basic HTML:

```
<div class="thingy"></div>
```

When the `<div>` is clicked, it will move to the right, as expected. However, whenever it is hovered over while it is returning to it's original position, it will snap back immediately.

I want it to, while returning to it's original position from being clicked, to be able to swap it's `background-color` (or any other property) then fade back to it's normal values without overriding any other transition currently going on.

For the purposes of the code, I can only use pure CSS, and I cannot utilize `@key-frames` or any property associated to it, such as `animation-duration`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS variable for this task

```css
.thingy {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  left: 0em;
  transition: 
    var(--t-left,left 4s linear), 
    var(--t-back,background-color 4s);
}

.thingy:active {
  left: 10em;
  --t-left: left 0s;
}

.thingy:hover {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  --t-back: background-color 0s
}
```

```html
<div class="thingy"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, but (and this is 100% my fault) this isn't what I am looking for. I failed to specify part of my question, and the `background-color 0s` on the first rule should have been `background-color 4s`. I have edited my question to reflect both.